# Microsoft Graph API get message returns empty string

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am querying to get a single message from the Microsoft graph API like the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<name>/messages/<id>
```

However, i am getting a response that is just an empty string. If i make the same request using the beta version of the api like the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<name>/messages/<id>
```

The email in question is a calendar share invitation of content-type of `"application/ms-tnef"` and content-class of `"Sharing"` in the email headers.

I can't find any documentation indicating this is a known issue in the system. Is there any way to get this to work in the graph API or is the only work-around is to use the beta version instead?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), and recreating your request using their demo accounts returns a result in v1.0. I assumed by name you meant the user's email address and I made the same request using the Guid id of the user.

```
 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com/messages/AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OABGAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURBwAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEMAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAHi4GJzAAA=
```

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038/messages/AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OABGAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURBwAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEMAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAIgOnGGAAA=
```

Have you attempted the same request using graph explorer?